# Emacs `apropos' programmatically?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a function I can run to return all functions, variables etc, like the `apropos` command, but without the side-effects of opening a buffer for user-interaction? I just want a list or similar returned, not a buffer opened and presented to the user.

Or perhaps it's trivial to implement manually? If so, pointers in the right direction would be excellent :)

Comment: @wvxvw I think apropos-internal is actually what I was looking for ;) It seems to just return a list of Symbols, which is what I need.

Comment: @wvxvw make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way I found about `apropos-internal`.

- <kbd>C-h f</kbd>`apropos`
- In the `*Help*` buffer, moved the point to the `apropos.el` and <kbd>RET</kbd>.
- The later opened `apropos.el` at the function definition, which, all it does, basically, it calls the `apropos-internal`. <kbd>M-.</kbd> (requires `elisp-slime-nav`), or you could repeat the <kbd>C-h f</kbd> procedure. Will take you to the C Emacs sources, where `apropos-internal` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, you normally do it via `mapatoms` which let you iterate over all the symbols, after which you can check `fboundp` and other properties to select the symbols you want.